# Can one initiate/start an app by observing user behaviour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I want to know how much my IOS app can see of the users behaviour when they have not unlocked their phone? It would tell mewhether I can use their behaviour to trigger my app to launch?

Acceptance Criteria:

How much of the users behaviour can I see when the device is locked?

- Screen touch/gesture?
- Noise?
- Camera?
- Vibration?

Comment: For an iOS question, you should not tag Android

Comment: human error.. 
Can you please guide me about this topic ?

Comment: First things first, does iOS allow you to spy on your user? RUn background threads without users knowledge? I dont think so -- Its not as open as Android. A Cron Job is impossible in iOS!

Comment: yeah I have read some articles some of features related OS we can't interrupt.

Comment: @Nun'eChai we can get user info in IOS 8 using Touch id.for reference please check this link https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LocalAuthentication_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014520-CH1

Comment: @Austin_ak My Question is:
Can we launch an app with some gestures when the phone is in locked state ?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch your app with a gesture on your app's notifications when they are active if the user allows them on the lock screen.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

You can launch your app in the background in response to a geofence if the user allows you access to location.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

Comment: Thanks @fruit for your answer. I have also done R.N.D on it after posting question. we have no option to do this. Apple not allowed to do this to open application like in android its possible to open application by swipe gesture on lock screen. What is your opinion ?

Comment: Notifications are your only option as I detailed in my answer.

Comment: yup, its only option I agreed.